# XSLT Variables Values

Tags: xml, variables, xslt

Here is a copy of a portion of my XSLT

What I would like todo is set the value of the variable 16863784, however when I run my XSLT the value is blank.
Why is my XSLT not saving the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, this:

```
<xsl:variable name="MEDIA_ID" select="//MEDIAITEMS_ROW/@MEDIA_ID"/>
```

needs to be:

```
<xsl:variable name="MEDIA_ID" select="//MEDIAITEMS_ROW/MEDIA_ID"/>
```

since `MEDIA_ID` is a *child* of `MEDIAITEMS_ROW`, not its *attribute*.

For another, this entire part:

```
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$MEDIA_ID != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="$MEDIA_ID" />
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

needs to be removed.